# how can generate random elements from an array using faker (not to be null and to have at least 6 elements)

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-8, faker

I have this code:

```php
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'feature' => $this->faker->randomElement([
            'A/C: Front',
            'A/C: Rear',
            'Backup Camera',
            'Cruise Control',
            'A/C: Front',
            'A/C: Rear',
            'Backup Camera',
            'Cruise Control',
            'Power Steering',
            'Hands-Free',
            'Heated Seats',
            'Keyless Entry',
            'Sunroof',
            'Airbag: Driver',
            'Airbag: Passenger',
            'Fog Lights',
            'Third Row Seats',
            'Navigation'
        ]),
    ];
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
<div class="row mt-3 mb-5">
    @foreach($post->features as $feature)
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            <i class="fas fa-check-square mr-2"> Feature:</i>{{$feature->feature}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

The result I get is sometimes 1 element or 2 elements, other times I don't get any.

Comment: How about using common https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: The randomElement call looks ok. Are you sure it is not related to the availability of $post->features in your database? If you want multiple random values use randomElements() instead (notice the plural) with the number of incidents you want as the 2nd parameter

Comment: @biesior yeah i could, i was looking for other option, a defined one from faker

Comment: I don't know what faker's method randomElement() does exactly, but what you describe can be done with array_rand(), so what is the reason for using some workarounds? It returns n random keys, so you can get these elements from array

Comment: randomElements($array = array ('a','b','c'), $count = 1) // array('c')

https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

@Malta yeah i see it it should work but i get an error:


Array to string conversion

  at D:\laragon\www\wbd6204-final\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php:509
    505▕
    506▕         $result = array_shift($segments);
    507▕
    508▕         foreach ($segments as $segment) {
  ➜ 509▕             $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
    510▕         }
    511▕
    512▕         return $result;
    513▕     }

Comment: @biesior

here u go//// 
 randomElements($array = array ('a','b','c'), $count = 1) // array('c')

u can find many here => https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

its just cleaner

Comment: But I don't want to search... Posting questions at SO you need to put as many details as possible. if referencing some method in the repository at least tell us what is the file and line number where it is declared. BTW, just wrote a sample code with your data and array_rand() just in few seconds. It works as I think you want it to work.

Comment: @biesior ur answer is correct man